# Prove that $\angle BAH = \angle CAO$.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, angle

Let $O$ and $H$ denote the circumcenter and the orthocenter of an acute triangle $\triangle ABC$ respectively, Prove that $\angle BAH = \angle CAO$.

[image]

The only thing that I've managed to get is $$\angle CAO+\angle OBA+\angle BCO= 90^{\circ}$$
That’s because $OB, OA$ and $OC$ are all radiuses of $(C)$.

Comment: You have $\angle BAH=90^{\circ}-\angle B$ and $\angle AOC=2\angle B$ (why?). Can you continue now?

Comment: God! I forgot about the Inscribed angle Theorem. @richrow